# Azure webjob calling internal service

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I have a console app that calls a WCF service.  This WCF service is on a Azure Cloud Service VM, and the WCF service is only accessible internally (using Windows creds).  The Cloud Services VM has been added to our domain.

I have deployed this console app as an Azure webjob.  It is living in an Azure App Services Web App by itself - there is no related web app.

When I run the webjob, I get a "System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at..." exception.  Which seems to be expected since the Azure App Services Web App is not on the domain or talking to internal DNS.

My question, can/how can I add the VM that is backing the Azure App Services Wep App to our domain?  And if not, what options are there for getting this webjob to talk to internal DNS?

Comment: This is way too broad to be answerable on SO. You are likely looking for Azure Service Bus  (i.e. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-hybrid-app-using-service-bus-relay/ for guide) or similar proxy solution.

Comment: Thanks for link.  How about just this, can I add an Azure App Service to a domain?  I have researched quite a bit and have not found any definitive answer or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general when trying to connect with on-premise resources or other private networks from within Azure, there are a few options that you can check out:

**Option #1**: App Service Environents: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-app-service-environment-intro/

> App Service Environments are isolated to running only a single customer's applications, and are always deployed into a virtual network. Customers have fine-grained control over both inbound and outbound application network traffic, and applications can establish high-speed secure connections over virtual networks to on-premises corporate resources.

This will give you the most flexibility because of the virtual network, but at the highest cost as it is a premium offering.

**Option #2**: App Service Hybrid Connections: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/integration-hybrid-connection-overview/

> Hybrid Connections are a feature of Azure BizTalk Services. Hybrid Connections provide an easy and convenient way to connect the Web Apps feature in Azure App Service (formerly Websites) and the Mobile Apps feature in Azure App Service (formerly Mobile Services) to on-premises resources behind your firewall.

I'm less familiar with this option, but it's design to work with App Service for these types of scenarios. It may be difficult to use if you require access to an internal DNS or domain controller, however.

**Option #3**: Service Bus Relay: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay/

> The Service Bus relay service enables you to build hybrid applications that run in both an Azure datacenter and your own on-premises enterprise environment. The Service Bus relay facilitates this by enabling you to securely expose Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) services that reside within a corporate enterprise network to the public cloud, without having to open a firewall connection, or require intrusive changes to a corporate network infrastructure.

This option has been around for a while and is especially designed for connecting to WCF services.  It's not specific to Azure App Service (as you can probably tell from the article) but it might still be a good, fairly light-weight fit for your scenario.  However, it also will not help you with DNS and on-premise domain controller.